# How to enforce Orientation in TabBar App

Tags: ios, uitabbar, screen-orientation

All,

When I rotate my iPhone, my app is orientating to landscape even though I did not specify "landscape" anyplace. Any advice on how to troubleshoot/fix?

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

would try setting this in your view controllers first.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

sometimes if needed you can use lines like this to force also

```
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];
```

also the plist looks like:

```
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
```